# armadillo reshape from vector to cube

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I would like to take an `arma::vec` object and reshape it to an `arma::cube` object.

For example:

```
vec param(mm*n*g);
param.randn();
cube LL = reshape(param,mm,n,g); // this line doesn't work
```

The easiest way I can get this to work is:

```
paramtemp = as<NumericVector>(wrap(param));
cube LL(paramtemp.begin(),mm,n,g);
```

But surely there is a more elegant way?

Answer (score 3):

Many Armadillo classes provide constructors which take an argument that is a pointer to another memory location; generally this will be a `begin` iterator of another object. For example,

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::cube to_cube(int x, int y, int z) {
    arma::vec v(x * y * z);
    v.randn();

    arma::cube res((const double*)v.begin(), x, y, z);
    return res;
}

/***R

to_cube(3, 3, 3)
# , , 1
#
#            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
# [1,] -0.8052190 0.5206867  0.4562287
# [2,]  0.6407149 0.8247035 -0.2375103
# [3,] -0.2766542 0.0527188 -1.2807390
#
# , , 2
#
#             [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
# [1,] -0.49995982  0.7240956  0.66634699
# [2,]  0.06367092 -0.7991327 -0.36003560
# [3,] -0.90958952 -0.4431064  0.05952237
#
# , , 3
#
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
# [1,] 0.457159  1.6725911 -0.9299367
# [2,] 1.205733  0.6185083  0.3805266
# [3,] 0.545668 -0.4356577 -0.9111175

*/
```

---

I'm not sure if the cast to `const double*` is strictly necessary, but it is there to distinguish between the following two constructors,

- `cube(const ptr_aux_mem, n_rows, n_cols, n_slices)`
- `cube(ptr_aux_mem, n_rows, n_cols, n_slices, copy_aux_mem = true, strict = false)`

where the first (which is the intention above) is a read-only copy.

Comment: Using `.cbegin()` would certainly distinguish it from the second constructor.